# How to display WordPress admin bar item based on current user capability

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a link in the WordPress admin bar as long as the currently logged in user has a specific capability.

This is what I've put into functions.php but nothing seems to be appearing in the admin bar.

```
function add_admin_bar_link() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return;
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'whatever_link',
        'title' => __( 'Link to whatever' ),
        'href' => __( 'https://linktowhatever.com' ),
    ) );
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_admin_bar_link', 25 );
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Comment this 2 lines and check. `manage_options` means admin.

`//if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
            //return;`

```
 function add_admin_bar_link() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    //if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        //return;


    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id' => 'whatever_link',
    'title' => __( 'Link to whatever'),
    'href' => __('https://linktowhatever.com'),
    ) );
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_admin_bar_link',25);
```